# Numbering rows in array environment

Tags: numbering, diagrams, arrays, commutative-diagrams

I would like to (use the `\label` - `\ref` mechanism to) number as equations the first and third rows in the following diagram:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}    
    \begin{equation} 
    \begin{array}{cccccccccc}
    1 & \longrightarrow &A  & \longrightarrow & B \times C & \overset{\pi}\longrightarrow & D & \longrightarrow & 1 \phantom{\, ,} \\
&&\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{$\leqslant$}&&\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{$\leqslant$}&&\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{$\leqslant$}\\
1 & \longrightarrow &a \cap b  & \longrightarrow & c & \longrightarrow & c \pi & \longrightarrow & 1 \, , 
     \end{array}
     \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Although I have done some research, none of the solutions found (using align,  alignat, etc.) worked well with my diagram. Do you have any suggestions? Concretely, which is the most suitable environment to use, and how?

Comment: @LaRiFaRi -- I guess he means the rows in fact. If you compile the example it is rather clear.

Comment: Do you need to refer to those numbers using the `\label`-`\ref`-mechanism?

Comment: I mean rows indeed, I'd like to refer the two short exact sequences (rows) independently.

Comment: Yes @Ruben, should I edit the question accordingly?

Comment: Adding that information is important in my eyes ;)

Comment: BTW: you might want to use something like `tikz-cd` for commutative disagrams instead of relying on `array`, much more featues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you requested here is a solution usind `tikz-cd`. It uses a custom labeling macro `\cdlabel` that throws out the current line of the diagram and generates a label named by the first argument. You can `\ref` it as usual.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{cd}

\newcounter{cdrow}
\newcommand\cdlabel[1]{%
  \refstepcounter{cdrow}
  \label{#1}
  (\thecdrow)
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
  1 \arrow[r] & A \arrow[r] & B \times C \arrow[r, "\pi"] & D \arrow[r] & 1 & \cdlabel{eq1}\\
  & \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{$\leqslant$} & \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{$\leqslant$} & \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{$\leqslant$} && \\
  1 \arrow[r] & a \cap b  \arrow[r] & c \arrow[r] & c\pi \arrow[r] & 1 & \cdlabel{eq2}
\end{tikzcd}
%
%1st line: eq. \ref{eq1}, 2nd line: eq. \ref{eq2}.
\end{document}
```

[image: output_crop]

Comment: Great! Now my doubt is which answer accept ;). Maybe you want to join both answers in a single one.

Comment: @suitangi, if you find it helpful you can upvote it. The solutions are quite different. So, I'd say we'll keep them separate. Regarding your question which to accept: The `tikz-cd` approach is more "diagram-ish" and a little bit cleaner overall. The `alignat` approach involves more hacking but sticks closer to your original idea of using some kind of ams array environment. And consider the user interface of the labeling mechanism. There are downsides and pitfalls in both solutions. I hope that helps you to decide.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `alignat` (in which the rows get numbered by default) instead of `array`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{alignat}{10}
  1 & \longrightarrow & A & \longrightarrow & B \times C & \overset{\pi}\longrightarrow & D & \longrightarrow & 1 \phantom{\, ,} \label{eq1}\\
    && \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{$\leqslant$} && \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{$\leqslant$} && \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{$\leqslant$}   \nonumber\\
  1 & \longrightarrow &a \cap b  & \longrightarrow & c & \longrightarrow & c \pi & \longrightarrow & 1 \, ,                      \label{eq2}
\end{alignat}
\end{document}
```

[image: output_crop-inbetween]

However, the default settings in `alignat` for the positiong of the cell content were designed for equations (resp. parts of equations) and don't match the requirements for your diagram or for diagrams in general (see the above figure).

To fix this you can use a custom version of `alignat` where you modify the positioning and spacing. I called this environment `labeledcd`. Note that it takes one argument, which specifies the number of columns as in `alignat`. (The argument in fact gets directly passed to `alignat`.)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{labeledcd}[1]{%
  \def\align@preamble{%
     &\hfil
      \strut@
      \setboxz@h{\@lign$\m@th\displaystyle{####}$}%
      \ifmeasuring@\savefieldlength@\fi
      \set@field
      \hfil
      \tabskip\tabcolsep
     &\setboxz@h{\@lign$\m@th\displaystyle{{}####}$}%
      \ifmeasuring@\savefieldlength@\fi
      \set@field
      \hfil
      \tabskip\tabcolsep
  }%
  \alignat{#1}
}{%
  \endalignat
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{labeledcd}{10}
  1 & \longrightarrow & A & \longrightarrow & B \times C & \overset{\pi}\longrightarrow & D & \longrightarrow & 1              \label{eq1}\\
    && \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{$\leqslant$} && \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{$\leqslant$} && \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{$\leqslant$} \nonumber\\
  1 & \longrightarrow &a \cap b  & \longrightarrow & c & \longrightarrow & c \pi & \longrightarrow & 1                         \label{eq2}
\end{labeledcd}
1st line: eq. \ref{eq1}, 2nd line: eq. \ref{eq2}.
\end{document}
```

[image: output_crop]

Comment: +1 thank you, this works fine. I'd like to know, though, whether this can be accomplished without such kind of customizing. Or should I understand that what I am asking for is not implemented in any standard Latex package? What about using tikz-cd as @daleif suggested?

Comment: @suitangi, as a matter of fact, what you're asking for is implemented in standard LaTeX -- as far as `amsmath` is considered so (I would do so). `alignat` does exactly what you are looking for. The longish overhead in the preamble is only added to accomplish the right positiong and  spacing. (I'll add a inbetween step in my solution) But, the basic feature is alredy there.

Comment: @suitangi -- `tikz-cd` is the package of choice when it comes to commutative  diagrams. But(!): There is no genuine support for the referencable line-numbering feauture you requested. You can build it in. I'll add another answer for this. Stay tuned...